# Nested formed by cocoon cannot be saved

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

#### Problem

I'm coding user's profile page on Rails.
I added a gem "language-select" for users to choose a language which they're learning. And users might learn several languages, so I added gem "cocoon" as well.
The first language which users choose is successfully saved, but others which were chosen by cocoon cannot be saved. I would like them to be saved and being showed on their profile page.

#### How I reached this problem

I added cocoon by refering this page and code.[README in github](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/blob/master/README.markdown)
However, "Save" button didn't react anything, so I made the form_for's method "post".

```
<%= form_for @user, method: :post do |f| %>
  <div id='languages'>
    <%= f.fields_for :languages do |language| %>
      <%= render 'language_fields', :f => language %>
    <% end %>
    <div class='links'>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add language', f, :languages %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then "Save" button worked, but an error occured.

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in UsersController#update
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
Extracted source (around line #211):              

        def handle_unverified_request
          raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
        end
      end
    end
```

Therefore, I added "protect_from_forgery with: :null_session" to application_controller.rb. Then the error disappeared, but the problem which I mentioned above occered. The first language which users choose is saved, but other ones which were chosen by cocoon cannot be saved.

#### （users#show.html.erb）

```
<h2><%= @user.language %></h2>
```

#### （users#edit.html.erb）

```
        <%= form_tag("/users/#{@user.id}/update", {multipart: true}) do %>
        <table>
          <p>Languages</p>
            <%= select_tag(:language,options_for_select(languages)) %>
            <%= render 'users/form' %>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </table>
        <% end %>
```

#### （users#_form.html.erb）

Partial of cocoon.

```
<%= form_for @user, method: :post do |f| %>
  <div id='languages'>
    <%= f.fields_for :languages do |language| %>
      <%= render 'language_fields', :f => language %>
    <% end %>
    <div class='links'>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add language', f, :languages %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

#### （users#_language.html.erb）

Partial of cocoon.

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <div class="field">
    <%= select_tag(:language,options_for_select(languages)) %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove language", f %>
</div>
```

#### （users_controller.rb）

Even though I settled "redirect_to("/users/#{@user.id}")" here, it redirects to "/posts/index" after press "Save" button. And the sentence "You're already logged in" which I settled at "forbid_login_user" in "application_controller.rb" is shown too.

```
  before_action :authenticate_user, {only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update]}
  before_action :forbid_login_user, {only: [:new, :create, :login_form, :login]}
  before_action :ensure_correct_user, {only: [:edit, :update]}

  def edit
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :description, languages_attributes: [:id, :description, :done, :_destroy])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @user.language = params[:language]
    if params[:image]
      @user.image_name = "#{@user.id}.jpg"
      image = params[:image]
      File.binwrite("public/user_images/#{@user.image_name}", image.read)
    end
    if params[:cover_image]
      @user.cover_image_name = "#{@user.id}_cover.jpg"
      cover_image = params[:cover_image]
      File.binwrite("public/user_cover_images/#{@user.cover_image_name}", cover_image.read)
    end
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Edited user's information"
      redirect_to("/users/#{@user.id}")
    else
      render("users/edit")
    end
  end
```

#### （application_controller.rb）

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
  before_action :set_current_user

  def set_current_user
    @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def authenticate_user
    if @current_user == nil
      flash[:notice] = "You need to log in"
      redirect_to("/login")
    end
  end

  def forbid_login_user
    if @current_user
      flash[:notice] = "You're already logged in"
      redirect_to("/posts/index")
    end
  end
end
```

I will add more code if it needs to be refered. Thank you very much.

#### Version

ruby 2.6.4p104 / RubyGems 3.0.3 / Rails 5.2.3

---

#### Postscript

When I choose only one language, it can be saved.
When I choose like several languages like below, the problem which I mentoined above happens. Nothing is saved.
But after putting "skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token" in application_controller.rb, only "English"(the last one) is saved (checked by rails console).

1. "Japanese" (chose by original form)
2. "English" (added and chose by cocoon)

Anyway, only 1 language can be saved so far.

Comment: You should really fix the invalid-authenticity token correctly. Saving only one item is mostly related to invalid html (using a html id for repeating elements). Can you show us what is posted to the controller? (it will show the data that is collected from the form).

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting! I'm very honored because I've refered many of your code and comments in other questions.

Comment: I have never touched "invalid-authenticity token" yet. Excuse me, but how can I show "what is posted to the controller"?

I've added Postscript above what I've done. Sorry in advance if it's not what you exactly wanted. I would appreciate if you help me out.